# MySQL query request from WorkBench client takes much less time than JDBC .executeQuery

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using this code:

```
double timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
double timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(timeAfter - timeBefore);
```

The return is `9904.0`

While when I do the exact same query from WorkBench MySQL client:

```
SELECT DISTINCT completeAddress FROM DB_M3_Medium.AvailableAddressesV2 where postNr = 2300 ORDER BY completeAddress ASC;
```

it takes `0.285s`

How is that possible?

PS: I tried it with different payload sizes and it's always approx. 10s with Java JDBC

**EDIT:**

I tried `PreparedStatement` with the same query as above and it took the same time, approx. 1s less.

I have also tried pinging with following code:

```
String query = "/* ping */ SELECT 1";
double timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DBConnect.getInstance().con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
double timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(timeAfter - timeBefore);
```

And the response was: `1306.0` which is not perfect, but better.

But I am still not getting what is wrong with it.

**EDIT2:**
I have figured out that the time that it takes is related to the amount of data in the DB (not the payload that I am retrieving). It appears to me like indexing didn't work. But why would I then have the issue only when I go with JDBC but not with WorkBench.

Comment: is the java code connecting to the db on a remote server?

Comment: Yes, but as you may see the time of 10s is taken while executing query, excluding connection. Same as payload size is irrelevant.

Comment: indeed but as others have pointed out in various answers. There are overheads involved. What kinds of timings do you get for pings between the two?

Comment: What is the connection speed between your Java connection and the database server? Ping time and bits per second would be helpful. Ten seconds is a long time.

Comment: Please check my edit. Thank you guys.

Comment: Try adding `LIMIT 0, 1` to the end of your query and compare the response times when you are only retrieving a single row.

Comment: The time remains 10s+. Good point though. But as mentioned before, it's not the payload and this proves it. I will check indexing again.

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J driver will by default fetch all rows, maybe Workbench only fetches the page shown instead of all rows.

Answer (score 2):

while you code in java, you are creating connection,then passing the query. That query is compiled(as you are using Statement) in the sql server and then you will get the result. This whole process needs some time.But when you execute direclty in workbench you are neither creating connection nor compiling,you are simply running the sql.Hence the time taken is less

Comment: Seriously? :D I mean you want to tell me that Java executing the query 20-40 times slower than WorkBench is standard behavior?

Comment: @OndrejTokar I dont think you will always get 20-40 times slower. The most appropriate way to check execution time is System.nanotime

Answer (score 0):

One thing to bear in mind is that the JDBC driver is pure Java, so you are probably running into some early JIT compilation that would not apply with the MySQL workbench. After the JDBC driver code has been through the JIT, you will probably see comparable performance. The real test for you would be put that code few more times after that and see what happens.

You can also use a `PreparedStatement` and see if that helps since that should be the API most comparable to what the MySQL workbench is using to avoid unnecessary recompilation of the query.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried `PreparedStatement` didn't really improve anything.

Answer (score 0):

As *@SpringLearner* suggested in JDBC every time you execute a query and made a new connection and cost some time. You can use a Data Source to avoid this overhead and better performance.